# How many configurations of two pairs can there be in a single poker hand?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the poker hand is sorted. So the hand is `2 2 3 3 4`. I'm coming up with a **poker hand can have four possible configurations where it has two pairs.** Suppose the hand looks like `1 1 _ _ _`, meaning this hand can have two more configurations: `11 22 3` and `11 2 33`. This leaves us with the last configuration of: `1 22 33`. If the first card doesn't have a pair, that means only the last four cards can have two pairs. Is this thinking incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is wat you are asking, but the unique non-pair rank can be lowest, highest, or the middle of the three occurring ranks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen haven't I accounted for that?

Comment: Are you asking how many sequences of cards with two pairs and a singleton can be formed?  Must the cards in the same pair be together?